# Endless API loading when using Playwright Mock API

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to create a test and need to create a mock for a POST request. This works great with GET requests for resources(css and js), but unfortunately, when creating a mock for POST request, it crashes into endless loading, even if I indicate that it should simply be processed without replacing the response.

My code:

```
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context(
    ignore_https_errors=True,
    bypass_csp=True,
    service_workers="block"
)
    
context.route(
    "**/dates",
    lambda route: route.fetch() # in original "route.fulfill(json=my_json)"
)
page = context.new_page()
```

As a result, I see "pending" in the console for a very long time (this could be all 180 seconds allocated for the test):
[image: pending load]

If I remove this route mock:
[image: successful load]

I tried using `page.mock()` or `context.mock()`, either way the request ends up in infinite loading.